# How to make a simple passcode

Tags: html

I am a beginner coder and I want to figure out how to make a simple passcode. My code is this:

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio">
<input type="text" id="in">

<button onclick="out()">

Click
</button>
<script> 
var inputone = document.getElementById("in").value;
function out(){
var ip;
if(inputone == "Pass")
document.getElementById("radio").checked = true;
}
</script>
```

I would Like to make this as simple as possible. Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the getting of the input value to within your function. Otherwise the line is run when the page loads and the input is empty and has no value:

```js
function out() {
  var inputone = document.getElementById("in").value;
  if (inputone == "Pass")
    document.getElementById("radio").checked = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio">
<input type="text" id="in">

<button onclick="out()">Click</button>
```